# How to edit a PDF using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext, edit

I need to delete a text in several PDF files, which is always at the same position. How to achieve this with iText?

I've tried to use the PdfStamper and draw a white filled rectangle over this. This was ok, but the text wasn't really deleted and each PDF Reader (Acrobta, Foxit, etc.) were able to mark the content (ctrl+a), copy and paste it.

Comment: You don't. This is how Adobe gets you to buy their products. It also isn't a [programming question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @msw itext is a Java library, so “how do I do X in itext” is a programming question.

Comment: OP is not asking for any tools to edit a PDF. OP wants to delete the text programmatically using iText library which is a popular Java library for processing/generating PDF files. So this is a programming question. @Gilles a few examples might be good, but otherwise I think your question is clear.

Comment: On the topic of deleting the words, though, this endeavor is not trivial. It is not explicitly supported by iText (manipulating existing page content is not). If it was meant as a feature for generic PDFs, it would be very complicated.  The OP seems to have very specific pdfs in mind.  If he supplied a sample document, it might be inspected to see whether the document structure allows for a simple solution.

Comment: @Giles Sorry, I was thrown off by the mention of `PdfStamper`. I'll now replace my earlier comment with "this is a dreadfully underspecified question". Better?

Comment: @msw Why is my question underspecified? If you know iText, you should know the class `PdfStamper`.

Comment: Maybe some one knows an other Java library which is able to edit pdf files? Or there is an other way of doing this.

Comment: @zzKozak can you provide a sample? Based on that it would be easier to decide whether your task can be implemented and which is the most apropos library.

Comment: I won't vote for closing the question, but if I did, I'd mark 'too localized' as reason. If @zzKozak would read the intro of chapter 6 of my book, he'd know that he's asking for something that is "NOT DONE" in general. As iText is an extremely powerful library, a good programmer could use iText to meet his needs, but due to the nature of PDF, there's no generic solution, which means that demanding "please give me code sample" doesn't make sense. Chapter 6 of my book is available for free here: http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf

Comment: @BrunoLowagie there are many application which are able to edit PDF files, you know it, and since I'm already using iText to create PDF files, I thought it could help me to manipulate a PDF file. I don't need to manipulate the original file. Maybe it is possible to copy the PDF content in a new document and discard the values which I would like to delete.

Comment: iText can probably help you, but your question is "too localized". You're asking for free consultancy instead of asking a SO question. I'm voting to close.